# Federation Authentication with KeyCloak: Bad Request Issue

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, federated-identity, keycloak-connect

We have integrated [Key Cloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) into the application.

Below is the code:

```
     protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            IdentityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            var httphandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            httphandler.DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //httphandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
            httphandler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
            httphandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
            var httpclient = new HttpClient();
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(Settings.GetSetting(KeycloakSettings.HeaderKey1, ""), Settings.GetSetting(KeycloakSettings.HeaderValue1, ""));
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(Settings.GetSetting(KeycloakSettings.HeaderKey2, ""), Settings.GetSetting(KeycloakSettings.HeaderValue2, ""));
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            Log.Info("code entered ProcessCore", this);
 
            var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                BackchannelHttpHandler = httphandler,
                //Backchannel = httpclient,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                MetadataAddress = MetadataAddress,
                ClientId = ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
                Authority = Authority,
                RedirectUri = GetCallbackUrl(args),
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                Scope = OpenIdScope,
                AuthenticationType = IdentityProvider.Name,
                RedeemCode = true,
                
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                },
 
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = (AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification) =>
                    {
                        Log.Info("code entered the authentication failed event", this);
                        if (notification.Exception != null)
                        {
                            Log.Info($"Keycloak authorization fail with exception.\n {notification.Exception.Message}", this);
 
                            notification.HandleResponse();
 
                            // This exception should no longer be valid if we use inject KentorOwinCookieSaver middleware before OpenIdConnectAuthentication. However, we keep this code to safeguard against future.
                            if (notification.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
                            {
                                notification.HandleResponse();
                                /* This line of code is the key to solve error 
                               IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. 
                               The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
                               */
                                notification.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
                                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                            }
                        }
 
                        notification.HandleResponse();
                        notification.Response.Redirect(accessDeniedRelativePath);
 
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                    //AuthorizationCodeReceived = ProcessAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
                    {
                        Log.Info("code entered the RedirectToIdentityProvider event", this);
                        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                        {
                            notification.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("kc_idp_hint", "saml");
                        }
                        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                            // If signing out, add the id_token_hint
                            var idTokenClaim = notification.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst(idToken);
 
                            if (idTokenClaim != null)
                                notification.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenClaim.Value;
                        }
 
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                }
            };
 
            // Sequence of this middleware matters. The KentorOwinCookieSave must comes before OpenIdConnectAuthentication.
            args.App.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
        }
```

Once I log in through KeyCloak it works but when I try to open the login page in another tab in the same browser and again click on KeyCloak to login then it shows a bad request (The size of a request header field exceeds the server limit) error:
[image]

When first time I log in I can see below two cookies had been created:

1. AspNet.CookiesC1 (Cookie size is 4047 Bytes)
2. AspNet.CookiesC2 (Cookie size is 281 Bytes)

and when I do log in a second time, two new cookies have been created:

1. AspNet.ExternalCookies.C1 (Cookie size is 4047 Bytes)
2. AspNet.ExternalCookies.C2 (Cookie size is 401 Bytes)

Please help.